# How to login logout when using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift

Hello friends I am using SWRevealViewController for menu. I used loginViewController on root , after login it comes to dashboardViewController. It working fine but the issue is with logout, I am unable to logout . I used two navigationController first for loginViewController and second for dashBoardViewController.

for login

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)


    let profileNC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SWRevealViewController")


    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileNC, animated: true)
```

Design of storyboard is

[image]

Can anyone help me,Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you tried with  popToRootViewController ?

Comment: Yes i tried, but due to my second navigation controller it remains stay on that controller.

Comment: Where is your logout button? In SWReveal menu or in simple view controller?

Comment: Its on navBar its comes on runtime

Comment: Better way is, make dashboardViewController as entry point. and check for logged in user, if user not login then make loginVC as root view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make loginVC as root view controller like this:

```
let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDel.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

Comment: Where this code I have to put, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or loginController

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: In "successfully logout" clicked event.

Comment: it's showing an error "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'storyboard'"

Comment: Don't put in AppDelegate. It is for Logout button. If successfully logout, then this code making LoginVC as root view controller.

Comment: Its working but after logout , unable to login again

Comment: Again use this code for making root view controller by changing identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside AppDelegate and use

```
func goToLogin()
    {
 let viewcontroller : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController()!;
self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    }
```

Usage: Call from any you want to logout

```
let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDel.goToLogin()
```